# Wildfly/JBOSS persistence error MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

We are migrating from Wildfly 8(for tests) and 9(for deployment) up to 21, Yay :). Unfortunately I am getting this error message when attempting to run the standalone.sh script:
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."projectName.war#ertDatasource": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."projectName.war#ertDatasource": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/TableGenerators

From what i have gathered online, this should exist in the hibernate persistence that we are using: hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final. Wondering what i may have missed?

Hibernate is set as a dependency in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And these dependencies worked fine while we were on wildfly 8 and 9. Wondering what i may have missed in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at wildfly pom.xml at https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/21.0.2.Final/pom.xml you see that:

```
version.org.hibernate is 5.3.20.Final
version.org.hibernate.commons.annotations is 5.0.5.Final
```

I suggest removing all hibernate dependencies and include only the API spec:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The version of jpa used by wildfly 21.x is 2.2.3.